# How to put if statement inside a lftp block

Tags: linux, bash, if-statement, eof, lftp

I am writing a bash script to download files from ftp server using lftp. I wanted to delete the files based on the second input argument.

```
#!/bin/bash

cd $1

lftp -u found,e48RgK7s sftp://ftp.xxx.org << EOF
set xfer:clobber on
mget *.xml
if [ $2 = "prod"]; then
  echo "Production mode. Deleting files"
  mrm *.xml
else
  echo "Non-prod mode. Keeping files"
fi
EOF
```

However, if statement is not allowed in the lftp block before EOF.

```
Unknown command `if'.
Unknown command `then'.
Usage: rm [-r] [-f] files...
Unknown command `else'.
```

How do I embed if statement in such block?

Comment: BTW, `[ $2 = "prod" ]` is quoting exactly the wrong thing: `prod` doesn't need to be quoted (it can only be parsed one way, as a single word), but `$2` could evaluate to any number of shell words, and thus any number of arguments to `[`, if not quoted. This is a category of issue that http://shellcheck.net/ can find.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A command substitution will do:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd "$1" || exit
mode=$2

lftp -u found,e48RgK7s sftp://ftp.xxx.org << EOF
set xfer:clobber on
mget *.xml
$(
    if [ "$mode" = "prod" ]; then
      echo "Production mode. Deleting." >&2 # this is logging (because of >&2)
      echo "mrm *.xml"                      # this is substituted into the heredoc
    else
      echo "Non-prod mode. Keeping files" >&2
    fi
)
EOF
```

Note that inside the substitution for the heredoc, we're routing log messages to stderr, not stdout. This is essential, because everything on stdout becomes a command substituted into the heredoc sent to `lftp`.

Other caveats to command substitution also apply: They run in subshells, so a assignment made inside the command substitution will not apply outside of it, and there's a performance cost to starting them.

---

A more efficient approach is to store your conditional components in a variable, and expand it inside the heredoc:

```
case $mode in
  prod)
    echo "Production mode. Deleting files" >&2
    post_get_command='mget *.xml'
    ;;
  *)
    echo "Non-production mode. Keeping files" >&2
    post_get_command=
    ;;
esac

lftp ... <<EOF
set xfer:clobber on
mget *.xml
$post_get_command
EOF
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. No wonder it does not work when I direct to &1. That explains it.

Comment: And btw, why "exit" in first line?

Comment: The `|| exit` ensures that we don't proceed to run the rest of the script if the `cd` fails. You probably don't want to risk downloading files into the wrong directory, right?

Comment: I don't really see the point of the all this inside the here-doc. Wouldn't it be better to put the logic outside of the here-doc? what's the advantage of your design? (I only see disadvantages).

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf, readability -- it allows the overall control flow to be seen in context, rather than dereferencing a variable in the heredoc and needing to refer elsewhere to see how it's assigned. And it *is* what the OP quite literally asked for. That said, there's value to showing an alternate, more efficient approach as well.

Comment: I find the second better `:)`. It would be even better if `post_get_command` were initialized; just in case.